# How to get rid of the smell and taste of egg whites? I throw up when i eat them

Tags: eggs

I can eat yellow parts without a problem. But I throw up when i eat whites.
I tried many ways to eat but failed. Scrambled, spiced, souce, etc.
I need to get rid of the taste and smell of the eggwhite. Any ideas?

Comment: If you're actually throwing up, surely the issue is not just that you don't like the taste?! Maybe you have some kind of allergy? Do baked goods with egg whites (say, meringues) cause problems for you?

Comment: I regret to say that your question is a little bit less than fully clear. Are you looking simply to separate the yolk from the albumen and then discard the latter? Or are you looking for a way to keep both and use them in your dish(es) without being able to to detect the latter when you eat or handle it/them? While it is clear that you've attempted to 'keep' the egg whites in the past, does this remain your goal?

Comment: possibly related : http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/40929/67

Comment: It sounds more like you should be going to see a doctor than consulting a cooking site.

Comment: I have to disagree about the allergy.  Food allergies don't present themselves with vomiting.  That's usually an intolerance.  I have the same violent reaction with mayonnaise and mustard.

Comment: I hit enter by mistake and took too long to edit.  :(  Part 2:  I have to assume the OP means whole eggs scrambled - not just scrambled egg whites. I don't like eggs either (but don't have this bad of a reaction). Is there a reason the OP feels like s/he should eat egg whites? There are other (better/higher) forms of protein. The occasional times I do eat eggs, there is enough stuff to help mask the egg - eggs benedict, scrambled with TONS of stuff in them (instead of omelet form).

Comment: If you find egg white so terrible in taste, why do you want to keep eating it? You can recognize it as something you hate, and strike it from your menu.

Answer (score 1):

According to McGee's, *Keys To Good Cooking* (Doubleday, 2010)*, p133,*

> The key to most good egg dishes is temperature control. Just the right
>   level of heat and protein bonding produces a moist, tender white and a
>   creamy yolk. Too much heat produces a hard, rubbery white and dry,
>   crumbly yolk.

to which he adds

> Eggs whites begin to solidify around 140°F/60°C

Exposing egg whites to temperatures anywhere above that may be playing a role in the problem you're experiencing, despite the fact that most people lack that sensitivity.

However, he goes on to establish additional solidification points for

> egg yolks around 145°F/63°C, and mixtures of eggs with other
>   ingredients usually between 160 and 180°F/70 and 80°C.

So to be clear, if you want to cook the entire egg together, the minimum temperature you can strive for is 145°F, a full 5°F above what is needed for egg whites alone.

If cooking the egg whites at *their* minimum required temperature can serve to prevent their developing the taste/smell you find so repelling, then it may be a good idea to prepare them separately and then add them back in later. But you'll have to raise the temperature of your pan to precisely this level and be able to keep it there, which may not be easy to do.

There remain electric skillets on the market with a dial for temperature control. But the truth is you don't really know what temperature corresponds to a particular setting until you measure it, just as with most ovens. So whether using this approach or a gas range (or even an electric range if you've that kind of patience), you'll need an appropriate thermometer. That however is a specialty item which can be hard to find. An oven thermometer with a flat base can do. But not even those are perfectly easy to come by.

For this purpose I recommend the likes of an empty tuna can set into the middle of your pan (so that it comes up to the pan's temperature), into which you drop a small piece of paraffin. (You'll have removed the paper from the can.) You apply heat at a very low setting and then work your way up in tiny increments until the paraffin melts. But the paraffin has to be the proper grade, touted as *mid melting*. It's melting point ranges between 135°F and 145°F. Careful shopping can produce a product that melts at specifically 140*F.

Once the paraffin melts (or even *begins* to melt), you know you've reached the desired temperature and can safely remove and set aside the can. And since you've worked progressively in small increments you can be confident the pan will remain at that temperature and, that is, rise back to it even after the eggs have been added.

There's also a time-honored method by which egg whites are made more stable, namely beating them in a copper or silver bowl. Since you're experimenting to uncover what might work for you, that's something else you might try. And best of luck solving this, as it's really a drag to have food sensitivities of any sort. Mine is to anise. I can detect it like a moth. Doesn't hurt me. Just don't like it.

Comment: That's because anise / fennel / taragon / licorice is disgusting.  Not quite cilantro level disgusting, but still pretty bad.  And then my mom had to mention that basil had a fennel-like quality, and now I can't eat significant amounts of that, either.

Answer (score 1):

I'm the same way. Add milk to the eggs while beating them for scrambled eggs. Mix well. Even add a little garlic, salt and pepper. Cook low/mid heat until the eggs are somewhat dry.

Answer (score 0):

This response is related to Tom's above....You might try low-temperature (otherwise known a sous vide) egg cookery.  Eggs cooked low temp seem to not have that sulfer smell/taste that some people experience. It's all about temperature control. In fact, egg cookery is one of the best uses for this method of cooking.  This will help: http://www.chefsteps.com/activities/the-egg-calculator

Comment: I agree about the temperature difference, but don't know if this is the reason. Personally, I'm one of those who hate the sulfuric smell of much-cooked eggwhite, but I also know people who are disgusted by the jellylike texture of little-cooked eggwhite. And besides, the sulfur is already present in raw eggwhite, just bound a bit differently. If the OP has such a strong reaction to it, the reaction might be still very strong when the eggwhite is still raw or little-cooked.

Comment: Perhaps, but I know many people who prefer slow, low-temp eggs because they do not perceive the sulpher smell/taste that they do when they eat traditionally cooked eggs.  So, no chemistry to back this up, but lots of anecdotal data.  Worth a try for the OP.